# import .db files/tables into sqlite database

Tags: import, sqlite

I have a zip file containing several .db files (~ 30 files). Each of these .db files correspond to a table, e.g., the "fuel_transaction.db" file contains a "fuel_transaction" table, "payment_transaction.db" contains "payment_transaction" table and so on.

I am very new to SQLite and whatever I've found is about importing CSV or sql files.. I was wondering if there is any way to import all these tables, i.e., all .db files (all at once) into a database in SQLite? Should I first create an empty database in sqlite and then import each file separately into this new database?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

For each database file (other.db) that must export tables to main.db:

```
sqlite3 other.db .dump | sqlite3 main.db
```

Or if you want to check the generated commands:

```
sqlite3 other.db .dump > log
sqlite3 main.db < log
```

Another method: (not so good as it does not import the primary key and column types)

First open the main database:

```
sqlite3 main.db
```

Then for each database containing tables to be imported:

```
ATTACH DATABASE 'other.db' AS other;
CREATE TABLE tablename AS SELECT * FROM other.tablename;
DETACH DATABASE other;
```